# Which would be the right way to Sign-In on my own server from an native Android app?

Tags: java, android, hybridauth

I have a website and my own server and database, I also have an native Android app. I need to allow users to be able to sign-in with their account from the website inside the app in order to sync information and other things they need to use. I've been stuck for a couple of days trying to figure out how to do that. I've found a lot of content regarding OAuth and AppAuth but they are focused on using an OAuth API to the job. Back on my server, I use Hybridauth for social login, but users can also register directly on the site. How would be the proper way to allow my users to sign-in to their website account through the Android app?

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it.  OAuth isn't meant for users to log in, it's meant to enable external services to access data on behalf of a user.

To make a user log in?  Create a POST endpoint on your webservice named login.  It should take two parameters-  username and password.  The body of the login service should salt and hash the password, then check if the hash equals the hash stored in the db for the same user.  If so, you're logged in and you return a success packet with a unique token to authenticate you for later requests.  If not, you return a failure.  The Android app would ask the user for their data, then send a request to the endpoint.  On success it saves the token and sends it in all future requests to authenticate yourself, either as a parameter or as a header.

This is of course the simplest possible version.  More advanced features would include expiring of login tokens, refresh tokens, possible lockout if you have too many bad requests, etc.  But the above is the basic idea.  Although really I'd look for an open source solution you can take, as there's quite a lot of complexity when you get into all the stuff mentioned above, and its a place where a mistake that leads to a vulnerability is probably the most dangerous.

Comment: Thanks. I was overwhelmed when start to search about this, I've never made anything like that before. I'm going to try this.